# Vote Early, Vote Often!

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes, up-votes

At this stage in a beta site's life, one of the things it needs most (along with questions, answers, and users) is **VOTES**. Voting from the community on questions and answers will help to determine what sort of questions we generally consider 'good' or 'bad', which will in turn help us to make important decisions about what the site's scope should be.

At the moment, despite over 500 posts on the site, [only six users](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=all) have voted more than 100 times. At this stage most of the users are those who committed to the site in Area 51 and followed it through private beta, so one would expect most of the posts to be exemplary - the site hasn't yet been discovered by more casual users who know less about site scope and the SE model - but only 33 of these posts have a [score](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/badges/20/nice-question) of at [least](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer) 10.

**We have some good content here!** And some not-so-good content? Either way, **let's get voting**! It's harder to tell that a post is good or otherwise when there's not much difference between any two posts' scores. Let's give new visitors a clearer indication of which posts we like and which we don't!

The next person to be awarded the [Vox Populi](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi) badge gets a gold star :-)

Answer (score 6):

## Yes of course. Voting is Awesome

This is exceptionally important for when a site is starting out. Even more so for a site that has a creeping scope, like ours will, and we don't know for sure where we will end up.

> We have some good content here!

Votes are supposed to be used to determine the best content. Helping those posts rise to the top to show off how exemplary our site will be. It is also a way to reward users for spending their free time here.

## We should establish a positive voting culture

It is important to try and establish a good voting culture. What I mean by that is people's votes can be influenced by how they see others vote.

This is not the case now but if posts had an average of only 2-3 votes then users likely could be reluctant to give more that a user would "deserve". We should strive to set the bar high!

Beta votes usually drop in frequency a little once a site goes public and that is normal. Some of my best rated post on WW.SE are the ones I had done while we were still private.

## Vote smart

What we don't want is people just voting for the sake of voting. If the content is good then is should get a up vote. If the content is less than satisfactory then a down vote or flagging might be required.

Down voting, much like up voting, is a very powerful tool. It is a way to trigger a poster that something is wrong or could be improved. However the problems are not always obvious. Down voting a post and not leaving a comment might not get the message to the user. If they don't know *what is wrong* with their post then they are less likely to fix it.

## Get out and vote

Its for the good of the site!

Comment: I am trying to see if I can find some SEDE queries to help make my case. Especially about the "voting culture" since that could be seen as opinionated.

Answer (score 5):

I'd put an emphasis on "Vote Smart" from Matt's answer.

I wouldn't say it's an issue that only 6 people have 100+ votes. We have different areas of expertise to evaluate questions on whether or not they're good, interesting, or effective. We've already seen a wide variety of tastes and skills.

Don't get discouraged if you can't find many posts that are relevant to you. You can always try to ask or answer those that you do. Or, vote on topics you'd *like* to learn more about.

That said, vote when you can! Make sure you browse around. We don't have that many questions yet, and you may have missed some that happened during the private beta.

Comment: Question votes are a great place for everyone to participate but be more selective on answer votes.

Comment: @Catija I think you missed out on some English there, or added too much.

Comment: That's what I get for doing two things at once.